# sql query to show average of each tag present in proficy historian

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, historian

I need to develop ssrs report in which user will provide a month as `varchar(2)` and year as `varchar(4)`. When a user clicks on a view report button, an ssrs report should display result as follows. (suppose if user pass month as 12 and year as 2013)

```
Date                 TagName               Average
12/01/13             Tag01                   45.23
12/01/13             Tag02                   89.23
12/02/13             Tag01                   2.363
12/02/13             Tag02                   45.23
.
.
.
12/31/13             Tag01                   55.24
12/31/13             Tag02                   95.24
```

I designed the following query

```
CREATE TABLE #tempval 
  ( 
     [timestamp] VARCHAR(30), 
     tagname     VARCHAR(300), 
     tagval      DECIMAL(18, 5) 
  ) 

DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2) 
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4) 

SET @month='08' 
SET @year='2014' 

DECLARE @startdate VARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE @enddate VARCHAR(30) 

SET @startdate=@month + '/01/' + @year 

IF ( CONVERT(INT, @month) >= Month(Getdate()) 
     AND CONVERT(INT, @year) >= Year(Getdate()) ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @enddate=CONVERT(VARCHAR, (SELECT Getdate())) 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SET @enddate=CONVERT(VARCHAR, Dateadd(day, -1, Dateadd(month, 1, CONVERT( 
                                                     DATETIME, @startdate 
                                                          )) 
                                    )) 
  END 

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @starttime VARCHAR(30) 
DECLARE @endtime VARCHAR(30) 

SET @starttime= CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(month, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd(day, 
                -1, CONVERT( 
                DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
                + '/' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(day, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd(day, 
                -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
                + '/' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd(day, 
                -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
                + ' ' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(hour, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd(day, 
                -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
                + ':' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(minute, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd( 
                day, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
                + ':' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(second, Dateadd(hour, 22, Dateadd( 
                day, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate))))) 
SET @endtime=CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(month, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT(DATETIME 
             , @startdate) 
             ))) 
             + '/' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(day, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT(DATETIME 
             , @startdate)))) 
             + '/' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(year, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT( 
             DATETIME, @startdate)))) 
             + ' ' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(hour, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT( 
             DATETIME, @startdate)))) 
             + ':' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(minute, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT( 
             DATETIME, @startdate)))) 
             + ':' 
             + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datepart(second, Dateadd(hour, 22, CONVERT( 
             DATETIME, @startdate)))) 
SET @query='select * from openquery(muri,''set StartTime=''''' 
           + @starttime + ''''',EndTime=''''' + @endtime 
           + 
''''' select * from ihrawdata where tagname=MURISERVER.MURI.DCS.ASSETS.87A.87A_FI_2101.DACA.PV  and samplingmode=rawbytime'')'

EXEC (@query)
```

But it displays blank columns but I'm not sure why.

Comment: What is output of @query ?

Comment: Your select statement seems completely wrong. How can you write "set StartTime = '''" inside select statement.

Comment: this query just for a single for 28-aug-2014. there are so many tags in historian. it displayed blank columns for that tag.

Comment: Can you show me output of @query? your select statement is completely wrong i think. can you please print output of @query for me

Comment: i have taken image file for it but i don't know how to post it on this forum.

Comment: This is what I see: select * from openquery(muri,'set StartTime=''7/31/2014 22:0:0'',EndTime=''8/1/2014 22:0:0'' 
select * from ihrawdata where tagname=MURISERVER.MURI.DCS.ASSETS.87A.87A_FI_2101.DACA.PV  and samplingmode=rawbytime')  your tagname and sampling mode need quotes, and I am not so sure that you can have a SET in an openquery.  The dates should be parameters in the WHERE clause right?

Comment: yes sir, but in historian i think you can pass date in set statement. i m not sure because i m very new to proficy historian i tried tagname and samplingmode using quotes but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found for an SSRS report to query GE Proficy Historian is to use dynamic SQL within a stored proc.

The prerequisite is that you have a SQL Server linked server configured using the IhOLEDB.iHistorian provider. That would look something like this once installed:

[image: Linked Server Provider for GE Historian]

You then create a stored proc as normal, I usually have a fairly generic proc which takes most of the arguments you'd want to query a GE Historian with. Example stored proc definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [utility].[Historian_GetData] @DateFrom DATETIME,
                                           @DateTo DATETIME,
                                           @TagList  VARCHAR(1000),
                                           @Historian NVARCHAR(100),
                                           @SampleInterval NVARCHAR(50),
                                           @SampleMethod NVARCHAR(50),
                                           @DefaultRowCount INT = 5000
```

However to keep the example simple, here is an anonymous block with some dates which will be used to query. Essentially, for each of the parameters in the stored proc you'd add them to the dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom NVARCHAR(100) = '2018-05-02 06:00'
DECLARE @DateTo   NVARCHAR(100) = '2018-05-03 06:00'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Result TABLE (TagName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, [Timestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL, Value NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, Quality NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)

BEGIN
   SET @SQL = 'SELECT tagname, timestamp, value, quality
           FROM OPENQUERY ([Your-Historian],
           ''SET StartTime = "' + @DateFrom + '", EndTime = "' + @DateTo + '",
             SamplingMode = RawByTime
             SELECT tagname, timestamp, value, quality
             FROM ihRawData
             WHERE TagName = XYZ'')';

  INSERT INTO @Result EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

  SELECT TagName,
         [Timestamp],
         [Value],
         Quality
  FROM @Result ORDER BY TagName, [Timestamp]
END
```

The result for that will look something like this:

[image: SQL Result]

So in summary:

1. Configure your linked server to point to your Historian
2. Create your stored proc accepting all the Historian query arguments as parameters.
3. Execute your dynamic SQL
4. Calculate your result as required, in your case some averages.